# "Cannot find the Template Property"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Im trying to attach a property, just like `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` to the `ItemsControl`.
Using it like below leads to an "Cannot find the Template Property" Error on build-time.
The attached property `AlternationIndex` works fine.

```
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" ... >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ... />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.Position" 
                                 Value="Last">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" 
                                    TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Value="0,0,0,4"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" 
                                 Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" 
                                    TargetName="Bd" 
                                    Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        ...
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

The code for the property is placed in the codebehind of the same WPF control that holds the template setter.

```
    public enum Position
    {
        First,
        Normal,
        Last
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PositionPropertyKey =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
            "Position",
            typeof(Position),
            typeof(ItemsControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Position.Normal,
                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        PositionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static Position GetPosition(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

        var result = element.GetValue(PositionProperty);

        return (Position)result;
    }

    internal static void SetPosition(DependencyObject d, Position value)
    {
        d.SetValue(PositionPropertyKey, value);
    }

    internal static void ClearPosition(DependencyObject d)
    {
        d.ClearValue(PositionPropertyKey);
    }
```

What is needed to make the property visible and usable in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not register attached properties like that, the owning class is *not* any control you intend to set the property on (- you can set it *anywhere* no matter what -) but the class in which the property is defined. So change the `typeof(ItemsControl)` to `typeof(WhatEverTheSurroundingClassIs)`.

Likewise you will need to target the property in the XAML using a namespace mapping for the namespace of your class in combination with the class name:

```xml
Property="local:WhatEverTheSurroundingClassIs.Position"
```